# Opening a live media stream using C/C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, streaming, media

Can anyone tell me how to open a mms:// live media stream using C/C++. I am trying to do this for days. but can not find any book regarding these information.
Please suggest any book or any helpful sites. or if you know how to do this please teach me.

Thank you 
A test stream

mms://a1926.l1856941925.c18569.g.lm.akamaistream.net/D/1926/18569/v0001/reflector:41925

Stream is NASATV provided by akamai.

Comment: The protocol is fully documented in the [MS-MMSP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc234711%28v=prot.10%29.aspx) section of MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

In VLC media player there is a pretty good example on solving this issue. Download the sources from http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/2.0.1/ (it's the .xz file) and then just get the source from .\vlc-2.0.1\modules\access\mms\ (if you're on windows 7z opens xz files). The mmstu.c file is your source for information.

More info can be found at: http://get.to/sdp (address taken from mms.c)

Since this is Microsoft specific protocol, further reading can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc251059%28v=prot.10%29

Answer (score -1):

Check live555 project, that would do the job.